# I'm getting error #1069 while trying to make a display button for an array

Tags: actionscript-3

First, sorry about french coding, it's a french school so I don't have a choice. I keep getting "Error # 1069 : Property 0 is not found on Number and there is no default value at U2A2_SommeElements / afficherFunction" I have no idea what to do with it anymore. Code is here : http://pastebin.com/5nyf3z7g Thanks for any help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see problems at lines 88 and 108. In the loop you use Array syntax on an integer. Change `entier[i]` to `mesEntiers[i]`

```
for (var i=entier; i < mesEntiers.length; i++)
{
    mesEntiers[i] = mesEntiers[i+1];
}
```

Comment: I've made the changes and it has made no difference at all.  I've put them in here [link](http://pastebin.com/5nyf3z7g)

Comment: i still see the same problem at line 114

Comment: Oops, I thought I had fixed that, guess I fixed a different button. Unfortunately the school is too cheap to buy me the copy of Adobe Flash CS4 that I require for the course so I won't be able to try it out until Monday. If it works I'll mark your answer right. Thanks for the help!